# How much can you focus sunlight?

Tags: optics, lenses

According to [this](https://www.askamathematician.com/2017/10/q-what-determines-the-size-of-the-bright-spot-when-you-focus-sunlight-with-a-lens/), the size of the focal spot of sunlight through a lens is f/110, where f is the focal length. A 61" fresnel lens with 86 cm focal length then has a spot which is 7.8mm high, which is quite large. How much smaller can the spot get if you add another lens at the focal spot to focus it further and then maybe another lens in the focal spot of that lens and so on. How small can it theoretically get and how small is it be feasible to get it in practice? Can the spot be focused down to 100 microns, 1 micron?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue  Remember that any "spot" of sunlight that you can make using geometric optics will, in fact, be a _[real image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_image)_ of the Sun.

Comment: Please note, if you like to focus rays of light onto a "small" spot, you do not use several lenses which are in each another focal plane.

Answer (score 0):

I've read elsewhere that the minimum is equal to the light's wavelength, due to interference scrambling all the light beams.  Visible light's wavelength (according to google) is up to 700nm, so that, I think, is the theoretical limit of how small it can get.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).